# Copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

**html**

```
<pre class="code"><code >from django.db import models</code>
<code >from general.model_mixins import TitleMixin, CommentMixin, BodyMixin</code>
<code >from hyper_link.models import HyperLink</code>
<code ></code>
<code ></code>
<code class="breakpoint">class CodeTypes(CommentMixin, models.Model):</code>
<code >    code_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,</code>
<code >                                 verbose_name="Тип программного кода (Python, HTML, JSON и т.п.)")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    def __str__(self):</code>
<code >        return self.code_type</code>
<code class="breakpoint"></code>
<code >    class Meta:</code>
<code >        verbose_name = "Тип кода"</code>
<code ></code>
<code ></code>
<code >class CodeSample(TitleMixin,</code>
<code >                 CommentMixin,</code>
<code >                 BodyMixin,</code>
<code >                 models.Model):</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    breakpoints = models.CharField(default="",</code>
<code >                                   max_length=100,</code>
<code >                                   blank=True,</code>
<code >                                   verbose_name="Строки с точками остановки через запятую")</code>
<code >    code_type = models.ForeignKey(CodeTypes,</code>
<code >                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,</code>
<code >                                 verbose_name="Тип программного кода (Python, HTML, JSON и т.п.)")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    hiperlink = models.ForeignKey(HyperLink,</code>
<code >                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,</code>
<code >                                  blank=True,</code>
<code >                                  null=True,</code>
<code >                                  verbose_name="Ссылка")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    class Meta:</code>
<code >        verbose_name = "Программный код"</code>
</pre>
<button class="code-sample-button">Копировать</button></div><!--.code-sample-->
```

**js**

```
function copy_code_sample($button){
    var $code = $($button.siblings(".code")[0]);
    $code.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

**Task**

The idea is to copy the programming code (without any html tags of course).
jQuery can be used.

My code not working.

```
document.execCommand('copy');
false
```

This false seems to mean that the clipboard is intact. Anyway, it is intact.

How can I copy the code sample to clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below JavaScript code & add content which you want to copy in div id="mytext"  button add   button id="TextToCopy" onclick="copy_function('mytext')"

```js
 function copy_function(id){
  var value = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  var input_temp = document.createElement("input");
  input_temp.value = value;
  document.body.appendChild(input_temp);
  input_temp.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(input_temp);
};
```

```html
<div id="mytext"><pre class="code"><code >from django.db import models</code>
<code >from general.model_mixins import TitleMixin, CommentMixin, BodyMixin</code>
<code >from hyper_link.models import HyperLink</code>
<code ></code>
<code ></code>
<code class="breakpoint">class CodeTypes(CommentMixin, models.Model):</code>
<code >    code_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,</code>
<code >                                 verbose_name="Тип программного кода (Python, HTML, JSON и т.п.)")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    def __str__(self):</code>
<code >        return self.code_type</code>
<code class="breakpoint"></code>
<code >    class Meta:</code>
<code >        verbose_name = "Тип кода"</code>
<code ></code>
<code ></code>
<code >class CodeSample(TitleMixin,</code>
<code >                 CommentMixin,</code>
<code >                 BodyMixin,</code>
<code >                 models.Model):</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    breakpoints = models.CharField(default="",</code>
<code >                                   max_length=100,</code>
<code >                                   blank=True,</code>
<code >                                   verbose_name="Строки с точками остановки через запятую")</code>
<code >    code_type = models.ForeignKey(CodeTypes,</code>
<code >                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,</code>
<code >                                 verbose_name="Тип программного кода (Python, HTML, JSON и т.п.)")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    hiperlink = models.ForeignKey(HyperLink,</code>
<code >                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,</code>
<code >                                  blank=True,</code>
<code >                                  null=True,</code>
<code >                                  verbose_name="Ссылка")</code>
<code ></code>
<code >    class Meta:</code>
<code >        verbose_name = "Программный код"</code>
</pre></div>
<button id="TextToCopy" onclick="copy_function('mytext')">Копировать</button>
```